# Sequelize belongsToMany when relation doesn't use the primary key

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm building a social network so my models are posts, users and the user-following-user relationship

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING
})

var Post = sequelize.define('post', {
  text: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
  userId: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER 
})

var Follow = sequelize.define('follow', {
    followerUserId: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
    followingUserId: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
  })
```

In order to get the feed of a certain user - all the posts from the users they're following - I'd need to be able to perform a query that looks something like this:

```
User.findById(13).then(user => user.getFollowingPosts())
```

But I'm stuck on the association:

```
User.belongsToMany(Post, {
      as: 'followingPosts',
      through: { model: Follow, },
      foreignKey: 'followerUserId',
      otherKey: 'userId',
    });
```

Generates a bad SQL JOIN condition, which I can't fix:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `posts` AS `post` INNER JOIN `follows` AS `follow`
  ON `post`.`id` = `follow`.`userId` AND `follow`.`followerUserId` = 13
```

I can't get Sequelize to user **post.userId** instead of **post.id**

Answer (score 0):

Found a good enough workaround:

```
Post.belongsTo(Follow, {
  as: 'following',
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  targetKey: 'followingUserId',
  allowNull: false
})
```

This way I skip User.blongsToMany altogether and query the followships:

```
Post.findAll({
  include: [{
    association: Post.associations.following,
    where: { followerUserId: 13}
  }]
})
```

Which generates:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `posts` AS `post` INNER JOIN `follows` AS `following`
  ON `post`.`userId` = `following`.`followingUserId` AND
     `following`.`followerUserId` = 13
```